# Django orm get other foreign key objects from foreign object

Tags: django

I'm puzzled with this probably easy problem.

My Models:

```
class DiseaseLibrary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subadults = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
    adults = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BoneChangeBoneProxy(models.Model):
    anomalies = models.ForeignKey('DiseaseLibrary', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='anomalies')
    technic = models.ForeignKey('Technic', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='technic_proxy')
    bone_change = models.ForeignKey('BoneChange', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bone_change_proxy')
    bone = TreeManyToManyField('Bone', related_name='bone_proxy')
```

From DiseaseLibrary I'd like to get all Objects that link to it via related_name "anomalies". Namely "technic_proxy", "bone_change_proxy", "bone_proxy" which are ForeignKeys to other models.

I would expect to get access by the related name "anomalies" and [_set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships)

```
>>> ds = DiseaseLibrary.objects.all().first()
>>> ds.name
'Some nice name'
>>> ds.anomalies
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x107fa4f10>
>>> ds.anomalies_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'DiseaseLibrary' object has no attribute 'anomalies_set'
>>>
```

How can I access all ForeignKey values in model BoneChangeBoneProxy through model DiseaseLibrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set the `related_name='anomalies'`, you query with:

```
#      ↓ related_name of the ForeignKey
ds.anomalies.all()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Willem Van Onsem , At least I was close ;) May I add another question (or update above). So every Disease can have many relations to BoneChangeBoneProxy. Each BoneChangeBoneProxy can have many relations to f.e 'Bone' Model. How could I filter like: give me all Diseases which have a bone named "skull" throuch BoneChangeBoneProxy() Model? Pseudo Code: `matching_diseases = Disease.objects.filter(anomalies.objects.all().filter(bone_name_contains="skull"))`

Comment: @Anatol: likely something like: `Disease.objects.filter(anomalies__bone__name__contains='skull')`

Comment: Coolio!  this does it! And for more: `DiseaseLibrary.objects.filter(Q(anomalies__bone__name__contains='Right') & Q(anomalies__technic__name__contains='Macroscopy'))` Have a sunny day!